# Age verification in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm creating some age-verification functionality for an iOS app. The user is presented with a `UIDatePicker` object, and the latest selectable date should be today minus 18 years. How vulnerable to inaccuracy is my code? How could it be leaner?

```
-(void)validateAge {

    NSDateComponents *today = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger day = [today day];
    NSInteger month = [today month];
    NSInteger year = [today year];

    int correctYear = year - 18;

    NSDateComponents *correctAge = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [correctAge setDay:day];
    [correctAge setMonth:month];
    [correctAge setYear:correctYear];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    UIDatePicker *agePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 240, 320, 200)];
    [agePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    [agePicker setMaximumDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:correctAge]];
    [self.view addSubview:agePicker];
    return;
}
```

Comment: Well, first of all, what about leap years ? If someone uses it on the 29th of february on a leap year, february 18 years earlier will always be 28 days long. I don't know what will happen with your code though, but I'd suggest to set up a test scenario for this situation..

Comment: I think *[calendar dateFromComponents:correctAge]* (third line from bottom) may crash..

Comment: That's an interesting point. I tested it by setting my system date to 29/02/2012. My datepicker set the maximum date to 01/03/1994. I think that's acceptable from a legal standpoint, as 'leaplings' can either have their birthdays on February 28th or March 1st. The app I implemented this in has been tested fairly extensively on a number of devices; no crashes yet.

Comment: Well, I think you're good then !

Answer (score 2):

Check this method. Pass value as minus 18 (-18)

```
-(NSDate *)offsetYear:(int)numOfYears date:(NSDate*)date {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setYear:numOfYears];

    return [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents
                                  toDate:date options:0];
}
```

Comment: Can you give a brief description of what this method is doing?

Comment: @JeffVanzella It offsets the the specific date by `numYears` in the Gregorian calendar. For example if you will pass `-18` it will go back 18 years (and deal with leap years correctly).

Comment: It would be better to  `NSInteger` for the `numYears` argument to better deal with 32bit/64bit differences (iPhone 5S was just announced to be 64 bit). Also, `numYears` is passed to `setYear:` which takes an `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

One basic idea about human-computer interaction is that a user should always be able to select something on the interface and go forward *somewhere*. You don't want to just leave them 'on hold'.

In your implementation, if the user is under 18, the interface will force them to lie about their birth date.

A much better idea would be to **allow the user to select any date**, but compute the difference in years to perform different operations depending upon the difference. You do this using

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:enteredDate
                                             toDate:[Date new] // today
                                            options:0];
```

After that, for people under 18, you can e.g. display an alert and redirect them to a different app.

It would still be possible for users to lie about their birth dates, of course, but the interface will not encourage it as much.